# How to move an iPod or iOS device from one computer to another without losing anything?

Tags: ipad, itunes, ios, data-synchronization, ipod

I have a new (Windows) PC and I am fed up with booting up my old computer just to sync my iPad and iPod, so I have just decided to install iTunes and sync with my new one.

Music, Pictures and Podcasts are not a problem to sync, I have them all on my NAS and they are in my library.

However, Applications are another matter.

I have right clicked the device (My iPad) and done `Transfer Purchases`. I have authorised my computer and all the apps that were on my iPad are now on my iTunes.

However, when I did sync, it still will not copy any new apps in my iTunes. I went to the device/Apps page and clicked the `Sync Apps` button, but I got the message that it is synced with another library and to sync apps will wipe everything.

I proceeded because I don't have anything important on my iPad... The only thing that was annoying was it lost the order/groups.

It did lose all the app data, but apart from a few high scores, I do not mind.

(I then performed an update and it did this again... I really don't understand that).

Anyway, Now it is time for my iPod and I really do not want to lose the order, grouping or the app data and I was wondering if anyone knows how I can sync with my new computer without losing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be rewritten in short form:

1. [iTunes: How to move your music to a new computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527)
2. [Where are my iOS backups stored?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766) - expand the section **About Syncing and Backups** and you'll see

iTunes places the backup files in the following places:

- **Mac**: ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
- **Windows XP**: \Documents and Settings(username)\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\
- **Windows Vista and Windows 7**: \Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\

I linked to the official articles since things do change and cutting and pasting the steps today might not be right if things change in a month or two. Don't worry - the article about music moves *everything* except the iOS device backups. If your device is working, there's no need to move backups unless you want to keep older ones or save time the first time you sync with the new iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general process to use is to enable iTunes home sharing on your old and new computer, and then drag the apps from the old to the new one.

First, make sure that your phone is synced with the old computer (so you don't lose anything), copy over anything that needs it from one computer to the other, and then plug the phone into the new computer, and tell it to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using iTunes Home Sharing, which is very useful in this case, I know that if you're on the latest version of iTunes you can download all your past purchases and such. Your other option is of course to actually find the files that include your iPod backups and transfer those onto the same place on your new computer. If you're on Windows 7, the files are located here: `\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\` The apps themselves are located in the iTunes media folder which i believe resides in the Music folder on your computer. I havent used iTunes on a PC since the windows XP days so I'm not entirely sure how all of that gets organized anymore. Transferring the backups would be my advice though.